# Beginner material for mathematical logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question

I am looking for study and beginner material to study mathematical logic. I understand that it is a very broad topic but I would like to know what the best path there is to learning mathematical logic. Where should one start? What are the best resources? If someone could paint a time line of events that should take place in order to gain a good understanding of mathematical logic, that would be fantastic. I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314461/how-do-i-start-studying-mathematical-logic) but it does not give the depth I require.

Comment: What's wrong with, for instance, [Peter Smith](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith)'s [answer](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic9-0.pdf).

Comment: @GitGud I had not seen that but it looks to be comprehensive. So are the resources mentioned in the guide the best or really good? I only say this because I am completely new to studying logic and I want the resources to explain step-by-step the formulations and the reasoning. I find that some of the resources move too quickly or expect you to know a host of things before you can learn the said topic.

Comment: To be honest I don't know, I haven't gone through Peter Smith's material yet. You should ping (or e-mail) him.

Comment: gekkostate: see Peter Smith's site [logicmatters.net](http://www.logicmatters.net/). Yes, Peter Smith's work is a great resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For a heavily annotated and detailed Guide to teaching yourself logic by a selection from the many many available books, try my Teach Yourself Logic at http://www.logicmatters.net/students/tyl/  It aims precisely to enable a student to move on "step-by-step". [Added: The current version is *Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide*, freely downloadable at the same URL, and also a v. cheap pbk.]
2. I'm not sure quite what you mean by "paint[ing] a time line of events that should take place in order to gain a good understanding of mathematical logic"; but TYL does have a crude map of the way areas of mathematical logic relate to each other which might help.

Comment: I am reading your .pdf right now and it contains exactly what I am looking for. The timeline, I am talking about is the correct steps that should be taken to learn logic. I find that I jump from one concept to another have holes but the tree on page 9 of your .pdf is exactly what I was looking for. To learn "baby logic" then first order logic etc. So, thank you.

Comment: Glad you think it is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I want to give an alternative approach to Peter Smith selection of books, what IMO is more aimed to philosophers than mathematicians.

IMHO the best introductory book of mathematical logic that you can read is the first two (or maybe three) chapters of *A concise introduction to mathematical logic* of Wolfgang Rautenberg.

Also it is very hard to beat, in rigor, the first two chapters of *Introduction of mathematical logic* of Elliot Mendelson or the first chapters of *Mathematical logic* of Tourlakis.

The big problem that I found in almost all introductory books to mathematical logic is that when the authors try to make things easier (as an introductory text demand) they do just wrong, appealing to informal reasons to show how to be formal!